# Showing two counting random variables are independent

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

We are given that $X$ is a random variable with $P(X = k) = p(1 − p)^{k−1}$ for $k = 1,2,...$.  I was tasked with verifying that

$E ({X \choose r}) = \frac{(1 − p)^{r−1}}{p^r}$

I noticed that the probability of $X=k$ resembles the formula for the variance of a Bernoulli random variable but I do not have much of an idea on how to start this problem at all and any small hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The support of the distribution should be $\{1,2,\dots\}$ for the probabilities to sum to $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)
. This leaves us with
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \binom{X}{r}\right]=\sum_{k=r}^\infty\binom{k}{r}p(1-p)^{k-1}$$

Turning our attention to the series we have:

$$\sum_{k=r}^\infty\binom{k}{r}(1-p)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{r+k}{r}(1-p)^{r+k-1}=(1-p)^{r-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{r+k}{r}(1-p)^k\tag{1}$$

The [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) tells us that
$$p^{-r} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+r-1}{r}(1-p)^k \tag{2}$$

Combining everything together (notice that $(1)$ follows from (2) by substituting $r\gets r+1$) we get
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\binom{X}{r}\right] = p(1-p)^{r-1}p^{-(r+1)}=\frac{(1-p)^{r-1}}{p^r}$$
which is what we wanted.

To apply the binomial theorem we should have $|1-p|<1$. This, however, should hold for the question to make sense in the first place (for the probabilities to sum to $1$).